# vsperfcmd.exe calculate code coverage inaccuracy

Tags: c++, googletest

I create a Cpp Project with google test in visual studio 2015. And using the vsperfcmd to calculate the code coverage, but get a lower result, some code line isn't marked as covered.
Here is my code:

```
 int FooBar::Max(int a, int b)
    {
        if (a > b)
        {
            return a;
        }
        return b;
    }
```

Here is my test case:

```
class FooBarTest : public testing::Test
{
public:
    void testMax1()
    {
        FooBar fooBar;
        ASSERT_EQ(fooBar.Max(10, 5) , 10);  
    }
    void testMax2()
    {
        FooBar fooBar;
        ASSERT_EQ(fooBar.Max(1, 2), 2);
    }
};


TEST_F(FooBarTest, testMax1)
{
    testMax1();
}

TEST_F(FooBarTest, testMax2)
{
    testMax2();
}
```

This is the code coverage marked by vsperfcmd, the return b code line is not covered, and the code coverage is 75%:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GEhOG.png)

Could someone tell me why or how to fixed it.

Comment: Please add to your question the output of your tests run.